Problems partitioning HDD for windows 11 dualboot
I'm trying to set up a dualboot of windows 11 (currently installed) and archlinux. I've done this before on a machine running windows 10 and I had no problems, however with this machine I run into errors trying to partition the drive. Here's the output of fdisk -l /dev/sda:
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 Gib, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/0 size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device    Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

From what I've been able to understand, the drive on this machine uses Advanced formatting, which is why the logical and physical sector sizes differ, this was not the case with the first machine which I dualbooted, however seeing as this format seems to be the norm, I don't think it's the actual problem ?
Secondly, the windows partitions, which should look like this:
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 209954815 209715200   100G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  209954816 463017983 253063168 120.7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  463017984 467836927   4818944   2.3G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  467836928 468858879   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment

aren't shown either, and fdisk erroneously reports the HDD to be 2T:
Device    Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

I'm pretty sure that this is because of Protective MBR which makes it seem as if the whole disk is one partition ?
The presence of Protective MBR is confirmed by gdisk /dev/sda:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning: Invalid CRC on main header data: loaded backup partition table.
Warning! One or more CRC's don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: ERROR
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 34 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
7521962741076038258 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Command (? for help):

However, fdisk's Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary. and gdisk's invalid main GPT header lead me to think that there's something wrong with the GPT or some other alignment or partitioning error.
Here's some more output:
parted /dev/sda unit s print
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/40968
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

fdisk /dev/sda
This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
It's recommended to umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap
partitions on this disk.

The device contains 'isw_raid_member' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and -wipe option for more details.

My questions are:

Is the problem with archlinux or with the actual HDD ?
If it is with the HDD, what would I need to do to fix it, preferably without losing any data ?

Any help or direction at all is appreciated, thank you for your time!

It looks backwards. You cannot really have a gpt partition. A drive is either gpt or MBR(msdos). Have seen before where old Windows install converted gpt drive to MBR but left backup gpt table at end of drive. Windows in BIOS boot mode requires MBR, and in UEFI mode requires gpt. Microsoft started requiring gpt with Windows 8 in 2012, but allowed BIOS/MBR for older hardware. Is Windows fast startup, hibernation, bitlocker on or drive in dynamic partitions? Probably best to fully backup & reinstall in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning.

I just checked from windows and it seems that the system is in UEFI mode with gpt, no mention of MBR. Fast startup is enabled, hibernation is not, I don't think that the drive has any dynamic partitions, as for bitlocker, the machine is a dell laptop and PTT is enabled in the bios which I understand is an implementation of TPM which involved bitlocker ?

I also didn't mention but a few months ago I was having problems with the machine which prompted me to do a factory reset (which reinstalled windows 8), followed by full wipe of the HDD and reinstallation of windows 11, could this have caused something ?

Make sure you have good backups. Does this indicate you have Intel RST on? 'isw_raid_member' Generally You have to change to AHCI and install AHCI driers into Windows. But with Windows 11 bitlocker, hibernation etc all can be issues.

Yes, 16gb of intel optane are installed. Is it necessary to change to AHCI for installing arch ? Without RST, windows runs significantly slower

Perhaps a bit of correction. Gpt drives do have one entry in protective MBR to says drive is gpt, so old MBR only tools do not try to modify drive. But drive label should be gpt not MBR  so entire drive is seen as gpt. So one MBR entry is correct. Not sure then if restoring backup partition table breaks anything or not.  May be related to Intel RST/Optane. I thought Optane was only a smaller SSD used just for hibernation of boot files to speed Windows boot, as it was slow booting. My Dell with NVMe only used Intel VMD driver with Intel RAID on and Ubuntu installed without issue.

Good news, you were right about intel RST being the problem, after having disabled it from windows, everything looks normal and my windows partitions show on fdisk, with no errors of corrupted GPT or misalignment issues. The problem is, like I said, windows is unusable without Optane acceleration, is there a way to keep RST and run linux ? Would switching from RAID to AHCI solve the problem ? Would reenabling RST after having installed arch work ?

So I tried switching from RAID to AHCI following this guide, however I was unable to boot into safe mode and consequently the AHCI drivers were not loaded, according to this post, you can't switch to AHCI if you have optane installed which defeats the whole purpose in my case. Was your machine using AHCI or RAID ?

According to this making Optane work with BOTH Windows and linux is not possible. So I'll try to install arch with Optane disabled then reenable once everything is working. Came across this post explaining how to set up Optane with linux using bcache. Thanks for your help @oldfred ! Would you be able to tell me a bit more about how you were able to make RST work on your machine ?

Mine had RAID and only NVMe drives. Have seem some with Optane remove Optane card and install a much larger NVMe or M.2 SSD. That would inticate Optane used M.2, but I really do not know. Intel has obsoleted Optane as it was expensive & NVMe has dropped a lot in price. Some re-enabled RAID, installed AHCI drivers from there into Windows, so they could then switch. Some Info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471365 What brand & model system?

The machine is a Dell Inspiron 5570. And yes, Optane does use M.2. If I have problems reenabling optane after the arch installation I'll see about switching to AHCI or running the system without it. Post 22 from the forum you linked says that Optane with a dualboot is not possible however this indicates that someone was able to make it work, albeit only on windows. I wonder if it differs between distros ?

Disabling Intel RST (Intel Optane) did the trick.

Ubuntu info, but should be similar: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 Also says you cannot dual boot, but says to install NVMe drive. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Optane-Memory/How-to-manage-optane-memory-to-dual-boot/td-p/659944

Dual boot with octane only works with no problems for certain configurations, as was said here, optane only works with RAID so switching to AHCI means I can’t use it.

Reenabling Optane after the installation of arch is not an option as this won’t work. The only other option is to use the system without RST, which means that my machine will be significantly slower. I think I’ll postpone setting up this dual boot until I can install an m.2 NVMe drive in the place of Optane. Thanks for the help!
